# Storing sessions in separate database in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-storage

For educational task I need to store sessions in separate database.

I've set `Shopic::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store`, but it stores sessions in my development.sqlite.

How can I setup sessions to be stored in separate database?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by setting

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.establish_connection(
        :adapter => "sqlite3",
        :database => "db/sessions_#{Rails.env}.sqlite"
    )
```

And in my migration I've added

```
def connection
    ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.establish_connection(
        :adapter => "sqlite3",
        :database => "db/sessions_#{Rails.env}.sqlite"
    ).connection

  end
```

Please, correct me if my approach is not very good